# I'm not getting the Cookie as a response from my server

Tags: detailsview

I send a post request and I need to get a cookie as a response with some more data.

I'm getting all the other data (user info, so the cors() is OK) and to get the cookie (at least in theory) I need to add `withCredentials: true`, but for some reason, when I deploy on netlify.com, does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your cookies has SameSite=None and Secure. Its important for Chrome

Comment: @Kevin try sameSite: 'None'

Comment: are there any errors in the dev tools exactly in network, cookies response headers?

Comment: if backend sent you cookies, but some config is wrong, there will be some errors about impossibility to save them

Comment: Difference between dev and prod - http and https. And so I assumed about SameSite and secure. But no errors looks like cookies are not sent, mb problem with something in backend code, that dont represented here

Comment: You send expires in miliseconds? Maybe try maxAge